# What is a good way to get a list of files from (a directory on) the sd card?

Tags: android

I'm happy reading and writing to a pre-set file, and could manually populate a listview, but I'm hoping there is an official(or not) filebrowser I missed, or other more elegant solution to present the user with a directory listing, and let them select a file.

Comment: sorted! the commands I needed were: path.list(); path.listFiles(); and  dialog.setItems(pathlist); - Didn't even need the listview :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
final String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
File[] files = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
} else {
...
}
```

Comment: Found a typo in the code, else it won't compile: Files[] files = ... -> File[] files = ...

Comment: There is also a method `.list()` that returns only file names, so it's not necessary to get all File objects.

Answer (score 17):

```
File fileList = new File("/sdcard");
if (fileList != null){
    File[] filenames = fileList.listFiles();
        for (File tmpf : filenames){
            //Do something with the files
        }
    }
}
```

Is another method you can try

Comment: Looks like it'd work, but it's better to use

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

over

File fileList = new File("/sdcard");

in case it is called something other than "sdcard"

Answer (score 0):

Code : listing all the music files or documents files or videos files , images , in android from external storage to listView.

```
ArrayList<String> filenames;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

> // onCreate method

```
songlist =  findViewById(R.id.songlist);  //songlist is ListView widget
    filenames = new ArrayList<>();
    getMusic();         // music files funtions
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filenames);
    songlist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> // getMusic() is method for getting and filtering all music files from external storage

```
private void  getMusic() {

    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String filename ;
    Queue<File> files = new LinkedList<>();         //Linklist

    files.addAll(Arrays.asList(path.listFiles()));  //adding all files of path in linklist

    while (!files.isEmpty()){
        File file = files.remove();
        if (file.isDirectory()){
            files.addAll(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));


        }
        else if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")){   //filtering files
            filename = file.getName();               // according to their extension
            filenames.add(filename);              //filenames is string ListArray

        }
        else if (file.getName().endsWith(".ogg")){
            filename = file.getName();
            filenames.add(filename);
        }
        else if (file.getName().endsWith(".amr")){
            filename = file.getName();
            filenames.add(filename);
        }
        else if (file.getName().endsWith(".wav")){
            filename = file.getName();
            filenames.add(filename);
        }
        else if (file.getName().endsWith(".wma")){
            filename = file.getName();
            filenames.add(filename);
        }
        else if (file.getName().endsWith(".flac")){
            filename = file.getName();
            filenames.add(filename);
        }


    }


}
```

> just change string values like (.mp3 , .wav)  to
>   .your_file_extension