# Retrieve lists of file in a directory

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good way to get a list of files from (a directory on) the sd card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716116/what-is-a-good-way-to-get-a-list-of-files-from-a-directory-on-the-sd-card)
>   [How to list all files and folders locating on sd card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638293/how-to-list-all-files-and-folders-locating-on-sd-card)

I am new to android sdk, I want to retrieve a list of files that is in a External Storage Directory .

I do not know which code should I use for this

How can I do this and does Android allow me to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to search for same questions first? Or just google? This is a very common thing and it's been described for hundred times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve files from the external storage, it is easiest to work with java [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)s, Start by getting the sdcard path, using the [`Environment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)-class:

```
String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

sdcard is now a `String` containing the file path to the sd-card (usually '/sdcard/' I think).
Add your own path to this base path, to get the directory you want to access:

```
String myfilepath = sdcard+"folder/";
```

To list the files in this directory you can create a file from the path:

```
File dir = new File(myfilepath);
```

And then finally, get a list of the files in that directory:

```
dir.listFiles(); //Returns a File[]
dir.list(); //Returns a String[] with filenames
```

*As mentioned, do some searching next time before asking a question.*