# How do I list files in SD card?

Tags: android

I have an android project that allow user to download pdf files, and it has been stored the files in the sd card, 
I want to collect all the pdf files in specific button, when the user click on this button it will show the list that contains all downloaded files.
how can I do this function
thanks

Comment: It has been answered before

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716116/what-is-a-good-way-to-get-a-list-of-files-from-a-directory-on-the-sd-card?rq=1

Comment: just google it you will find exactly what you want. here is a tutorial that may help you http://bit.ly/QXxmeq

Answer (score 0):

Here Your Code...

```
String ROOT = "mnt/sdcard/rec/";
private ArrayList<String> Files;
private void listRecordings() {
    File folder = new File(ROOT);
    Files = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] items = folder.listFiles();
    for (File file : items) {
        Files.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        // Log.i("FILES", file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```