# String array length gives null pointer android

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, nullpointerexception

In my code I am forming a string array dynamically.
Then when I try to get the size of the array by "length" property, the application crashes giving out the Null Pointer Exception.
Is there another way to get array length?

```
File Cur_folder=new File(""+folder.toString());
                String[] dirList=Cur_folder.list();
                int c=dirList.length;
```

Log cat:

```
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576): Process: com.example.nusearch, PID: 1576
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at com.example.nusearch.MainActivity$StartIndexing.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:97)
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at com.example.nusearch.MainActivity$StartIndexing.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-23 03:02:40.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1576):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Post your code then....

Comment: ok wait a sec..i'll post it

Comment: Seems the array itself is `null`.

Comment: post your code here!!

Comment: i have provided the folder with some files in it, then y the list function not doing its work

Comment: File Cur_folder=new File(""+folder.toString()); is returning null, debug it and check

Comment: Try this `File[] dirList=Cur_folder.listFiles();` and take a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716116/what-is-a-good-way-to-get-a-list-of-files-from-a-directory-on-the-sd-card)

Comment: ok i'll try those codes...

Comment: Which one is line 97?

Comment: @MD: `.list()` functions returns string[]

Comment: @user2820823 Go to this [list-filesdirectory-in-android.html](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/10/list-filesdirectory-in-android.html)

Comment: @Henry: `for(String val:dirList){}` this is line 97

Comment: @Henry did the last answer helped you a lot :D ?

Comment: @user2820823 Yo welcome!! mate..

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace is talking about Null pointer exception, it means your `Cur_folder` described as File object has not proper path.

When you call method `list()`, it can returns list of files in String array or null.
Here is documentation about `list()` method. It is not safe to save amount direct to integer.

> public String[] list()
>
> Returns an array of strings naming the files and directories in the
>   directory denoted by this abstract pathname.
>
> If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this
>   method returns null. Otherwise an array of strings is returned, one
>   for each file or directory in the directory. Names denoting the
>   directory itself and the directory's parent directory are not included
>   in the result. Each string is a file name rather than a complete path. (...)

Link to documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to check if folder **exists** and I also recommend you to always protect file access code with **try catch**.

```
int c = 0;
try {
    File Cur_folder = new File("" + folder.toString());
    if (Cur_folder.exists()) {
        String[] dirList = Cur_folder.list();
        c = dirList.length;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e(TAG,"Something failed. Check traces below for details!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// if any error happened then here you find c = 0
// if other case, c = number of files in Cur_folder
```

Notes:

- Using .list() you obtain String[]
- If you need File[] then try .listFiles()